# issue with CSS setting an HTML table width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the width of a table in a CSS file. My CSS file declaration looks like
`.specialTable {width:450px;}`

the css file is loaded before the `<head>` via `<linK`

in the HTML I am using it as

```
<table  id="OverallTable" class="specialTable" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000000" >
```

the above doesnt work.

The following works

```
<table id="OverallTable" style="width:450;" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  bgcolor="#000000" >
```

Can someone help with the CSS file please.

CSS file included

```css
:hover {font-size: 12px; color: #ff0066; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
a:active {font-size: 12px; color: #666699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/*  color: #FFCF00;  
    text-decoration: none;  used to decorated the link eg. underline*/
    
a.buttons:link {font-size: 12px; color: #FFCF00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a.buttons:visited {font-size: 12px; color: #FFCF00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a.buttons:hover {font-size: 12px; color: #FFCF00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a.buttons:active {font-size: 12px; color: #FFCF00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}



.clear {clear:both;}

.specialTable {width:450px;} 

/* .specialTable {width:auto;} 
style="width: 150px;"*/

body {font-size: 12px; background-color:#000000; margin-top: 0px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
 /*   scrollbar-face-color: #999966;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #000000;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #ffffff;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #666666;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #000000;
    scrollbar-track-color: #CCCC88;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFDD00; 
    background-color:#334433; 
    background-color:#333333;  grey
    text-align: center; */
    


form { margin:0;}


#container {
    background-image: url(../images/Gifs/greyBack.jpg);
    background: #333333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 355px; 
/*  width: 1247px; 
    border: #999966 1px solid;
    position: relative; */
    position: fixed;
    height: 791px;

}
/*791 1247*background: #666666;
position: fixed; ( to fix the container to the left) */
/*text-align: left; */

 

p {font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

h1{ display: inline; font-size: 7pt; color: #DDEEDD; font-weight: normal; font-family: "verdana", "arial", "helvetica", sans-serif; }
h2{ display: inline; font-size: 9pt; color: #000000; font-weight: normal; font-family: "verdana", "arial", "helvetica", sans-serif; }



.siteT3 { font-size: 52px; color: #FFFFFF;  font-weight:normal ; text-align: right; font-family: "Trebuchet MS";   margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0px; }

.siteTitle  { font-size: 30px; color: #AACCFC; font-weight: 200; text-align: center; font-family: "arial", "verdana", "helvetica", sans-serif;}
.siteTitle2 { font-size: 18px;  color: #AACCFC; font-weight: 200; text-align: center; font-family: "arial", "verdana", "helvetica", sans-serif;}


.siteTitle1 { font-size: 52px; color: #FFFFFF;  font-family: "arial", "verdana", "helvetica", sans-serif; font-weight:normal ; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: right; } 


.siteSubTitle { height: 23px; font-size: 16px; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;  font-weight: normal; font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", "Times", sans-serif;}
.siteSubTitleC4 { height: 14px; font-size: 14px; text-align: center; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", "Times", sans-serif;}
.siteSubTitleC5 { height: 12px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; color: #000000; font-weight: normal; font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", "Times", sans-serif;}

.siteSubTitleC41 { height: 14px; font-size: 14px; text-align: left; color: #CCCCAA; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.siteSubTitleC51 { height: 12px; font-size: 12px; text-align: right; color: #CCCCAA; font-weight: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}


.pLeft         {font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.pLeft10       {font-size: 10px;  color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.pCenter     {font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.pLeftB10B  {font-size: 10px; color: #000000; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }


.pLeftB12N  {font-size: 12px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pLeftB12B  {font-size: 12px;  color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pLeftR12B  {font-size: 12px; color: #FF0000; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pLeftB14B  { font-size: 14px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.pCenter10N {font-size: 10px; color: #666666; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pCenter12N {font-size: 12px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pCenter12B {font-size: 12px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;  font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

.jim14B  {font-size: 14px; color: #FF0000; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

Comment: You probably didn’t correctly include your css file in the html because the selector you specified is correct. Anyway I see you are clueless on the most basic stuff. You should go by simpler steps and begin with ‘<style>’ or googling for tutorials

Comment: Just as Diego said. It is hard to answer a CSS bug without the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the snippet below.

The styles are applied correctly to the table but it is not visible because you have dark background. Change the background color of your table or atleast `color` and `border-color`.

```css
:hover {font-size: 12px; color: #ff0066; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
a:active {font-size: 12px; color: #666699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/*  color: #FFCF00;  
    text-decoration: none;  used to decorated the link eg. underline*/
    
a.buttons:link {font-size: 12px; color: #FFCF00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a.buttons:visited {font-size: 12px; color: #FFCF00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a.buttons:hover {font-size: 12px; color: #FFCF00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a.buttons:active {font-size: 12px; color: #FFCF00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}



.clear {clear:both;}

.specialTable {
width:450px;
background: white;
} 

/* .specialTable {width:auto;} 
style="width: 150px;"*/

body {font-size: 12px; background-color:#000000; margin-top: 0px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
 /*   scrollbar-face-color: #999966;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #000000;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #ffffff;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #666666;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #000000;
    scrollbar-track-color: #CCCC88;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFDD00; 
    background-color:#334433; 
    background-color:#333333;  grey
    text-align: center; */
    


form { margin:0;}


#container {
    background-image: url(../images/Gifs/greyBack.jpg);
    background: #333333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 355px; 
/*  width: 1247px; 
    border: #999966 1px solid;
    position: relative; */
    position: fixed;
    height: 791px;

}
/*791 1247*background: #666666;
position: fixed; ( to fix the container to the left) */
/*text-align: left; */

 

p {font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

h1{ display: inline; font-size: 7pt; color: #DDEEDD; font-weight: normal; font-family: "verdana", "arial", "helvetica", sans-serif; }
h2{ display: inline; font-size: 9pt; color: #000000; font-weight: normal; font-family: "verdana", "arial", "helvetica", sans-serif; }



.siteT3 { font-size: 52px; color: #FFFFFF;  font-weight:normal ; text-align: right; font-family: "Trebuchet MS";   margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0px; }

.siteTitle  { font-size: 30px; color: #AACCFC; font-weight: 200; text-align: center; font-family: "arial", "verdana", "helvetica", sans-serif;}
.siteTitle2 { font-size: 18px;  color: #AACCFC; font-weight: 200; text-align: center; font-family: "arial", "verdana", "helvetica", sans-serif;}


.siteTitle1 { font-size: 52px; color: #FFFFFF;  font-family: "arial", "verdana", "helvetica", sans-serif; font-weight:normal ; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: right; } 


.siteSubTitle { height: 23px; font-size: 16px; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;  font-weight: normal; font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", "Times", sans-serif;}
.siteSubTitleC4 { height: 14px; font-size: 14px; text-align: center; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", "Times", sans-serif;}
.siteSubTitleC5 { height: 12px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; color: #000000; font-weight: normal; font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", "Times", sans-serif;}

.siteSubTitleC41 { height: 14px; font-size: 14px; text-align: left; color: #CCCCAA; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.siteSubTitleC51 { height: 12px; font-size: 12px; text-align: right; color: #CCCCAA; font-weight: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}


.pLeft         {font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.pLeft10       {font-size: 10px;  color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.pCenter     {font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.pLeftB10B  {font-size: 10px; color: #000000; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }


.pLeftB12N  {font-size: 12px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pLeftB12B  {font-size: 12px;  color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pLeftR12B  {font-size: 12px; color: #FF0000; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pLeftB14B  { font-size: 14px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.pCenter10N {font-size: 10px; color: #666666; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pCenter12N {font-size: 12px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.pCenter12B {font-size: 12px; color: #CCCCAA; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;  font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

.jim14B  {font-size: 14px; color: #FF0000; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<table class="specialTable">
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td> 
    <td> hii</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, I tried it but made no difference. I have uploaded the CSS file. the declarations </head>

<link href="stylesheets_V1/navigationBarM.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="stylesheets_V1/productInformation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Are other style declarations working correctly?

Comment: yes, they are. thats the confusing element to this.

Comment: It's okay. The background was dark. That's why the table wasn't visible. I've updated the answer. Have a look.

Comment: Amit, this is in a HTML 1 website, so I need to link the css files before the <body>. When i do it after the <body> the lines are in red when I look at the source code on the browser.

Comment: i just discovered that I had <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  before the docttype decleration at the top of the file. I moved it after the doctype and the CSS seems to work now. !!

Comment: Great. And, you don't have to link the css after <body> or inside <body>. Link it in the <head> tag only. Just change the border-color or background of the table(in the css file) so that you can see that the styles are being applied to it.

Comment: Thank you Amit for your help. Regards Jim

Answer (score -1):

perhaps the `css` file has a different name or is located in a different folder, and it is not connected correctly

```
css/styles.css
```